# Error on "pip install -U channels" command using for otree (Running setup.py bdist_wheel for twisted ... error)

Tags: python, django, pip, twisted, python-wheel

For a project using otree (http://otree.readthedocs.io/) I ran into some problems trying to install `Channels` in order to make use of real-time functionalities.

Because of the long output I tried to figure out the most important parts:

For full output see: https://jsfiddle.net/L4ccmr2k/1/

**Red marked output & output considered relevant from my side:**

1.

```
 Building wheels for collected packages: twisted
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for twisted ... error
```

2.

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/twisted
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/twisted/test
      /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/twisted/test/raiser.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for twisted
      Running setup.py clean for twisted
    Failed to build twisted
    Installing collected packages: twisted, daphne, channels
      Running setup.py install for twisted ... error
        Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6_/30pgp_bj17j3krgq_kt0py440000gn/T/pip-build-v4kcayoj/twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/6_/30pgp_bj17j3krgq_kt0py440000gn/T/pip-vpnlc5lo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

3.

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/twisted
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/twisted/test
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/twisted/test/raiser.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6_/30pgp_bj17j3krgq_kt0py440000gn/T/pip-build-v4kcayoj/twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/6_/30pgp_bj17j3krgq_kt0py440000gn/T/pip-vpnlc5lo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6_/30pgp_bj17j3krgq_kt0py440000gn/T/pip-build-v4kcayoj/twisted/
```

I'm using:

- macOS 10.12.6
- Python 2.7.10
- wheel-0.30.0
- pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
- Django-1.8.8
- Twisted-16.2.0
- asgiref-0.14.0
- autobahn-0.16.0
- channels-0.17.3
- otree-core-1.4.28
- pytz-2016.6.1
- six-1.10.0
- txaio-2.5.1
- wheel-0.29.0
- zope.interface-4.2.0

Answer (score 4):

try running these commands

`xcode-select --install
 xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
 xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

just to make sure your setup is properly applied

Comment: Thank you, it helps! But it could use "sudo" for 2 and 3 command