# Getting Errors while installing airflow using pip install apache-airflow in macOS Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, installation, airflow

I am steering my learning wheel towards airflow during this weekend and while setting up and installing airflow at local machine using pip install apache-airflow, I'm getting following errors:

```
(base) ItGuy-MacBook-Pro:~ gofrogs$ pip install apache-airflow






  Stored in directory: /Users/gofrogs/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/41/d4/fa/31df9cc56ee41572a4dfc1be7dfc87df59a5d6a7fd03e97eab
  Building wheel for setproctitle (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-wheel-78zrb1fy
       cwd: /private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/
  Complete output (10 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'setproctitle' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPT_VERSION=1.1.10 -D__darwin__=1 -I/Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/setproctitle.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/setproctitle.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for setproctitle
```

and

```
Successfully built thrift flask-admin termcolor alembic dill pendulum flask-login flask-swagger json-merge-patch tzlocal Flask-JWT-Extended sqlalchemy-utils Flask-OpenID
Failed to build setproctitle
Installing collected packages: thrift, flask-caching, cached-property, wtforms, flask-admin, lockfile, python-daemon, tabulate, configparser, markdown, sqlalchemy-jsonfield, text-unidecode, termcolor, python-editor, Mako, alembic, dill, attrs, pytzdata, tzlocal, pendulum, argcomplete, setproctitle, PyJWT, Flask-JWT-Extended, marshmallow, flask-wtf, Flask-Babel, marshmallow-enum, Flask-SQLAlchemy, prison, flask-login, sqlalchemy-utils, apispec, marshmallow-sqlalchemy, python3-openid, Flask-OpenID, flask-appbuilder, cattrs, colorlog, graphviz, typing-extensions, croniter, flask-swagger, iso8601, tenacity, funcsigs, json-merge-patch, zope.deprecation, gunicorn, apache-airflow
  Attempting uninstall: attrs
    Found existing installation: attrs 19.2.0
    Uninstalling attrs-19.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled attrs-19.2.0
    Running setup.py install for setproctitle ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-record-cl1apnxt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/setproctitle
         cwd: /private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'setproctitle' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DSPT_VERSION=1.1.10 -D__darwin__=1 -I/Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/setproctitle.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/setproctitle.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-install-hnedol5a/setproctitle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/7s/9jm62xrs77x3mvsjfkd_7fq80000gn/T/pip-record-cl1apnxt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gofrogs/Downloads/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/setproctitle Check the logs for full command output.
```

Could you please suggest me what needs to be fixed? Also, if possible please share link(s) to detailed explanation/tutorials about airflow so I/future readers can follow the best resources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on "pip install -U channels" command using for otree (Running setup.py bdist\_wheel for twisted ... error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400675/error-on-pip-install-u-channels-command-using-for-otree-running-setup-py-bdi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is typically related to Xcode toolkit.

Type this command in your terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

If that doesn't work, you can always try to update the toolkit first.