Montreal Forced Aligner won't install, and instead results in the error "metadata-generation-failed" and "Path not writable or missing."
I have been trying to install montreal forced aligner via command line and it won't work.  I use a mac, and have put in:
conda create -n aligner kaldi pynini

It installed conda, then I put in
conda activate aligner

and then
pip install git+https://github.com/MontrealCorpusTools/Montreal-Forced-Aligner.git

It gave me the error "subprocess-exited-with-error", and said this:
Collecting git+https://github.com/MontrealCorpusTools/Montreal-Forced-Aligner.git
  Cloning https://github.com/MontrealCorpusTools/Montreal-Forced-Aligner.git to /private/var/folders/s5/v7w0tcn146s5dcch213_nkdw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-_f8yhwwt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × git version did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git version did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I tried the other way they say to install it on their website and tried "pip install montreal-forced-aligner" on both terminal's normal mode and after activating python because it said something about using python, and it didn't work for that either.  It also says "path not writable" a bunch.  Is that important?
Basically, what do these errors mean, and what recourse do you recommend.
I have been trying to install montreal forced aligner via command line and it won't work.  I use a mac, and have put in:
conda create -n aligner kaldi pynini

It installed conda, then I put in
conda activate aligner

and then
pip install git+https://github.com/MontrealCorpusTools/Montreal-Forced-Aligner.git

It gave me the error "subprocess-exited-with-error", and said this:
Collecting git+https://github.com/MontrealCorpusTools/Montreal-Forced-Aligner.git
  Cloning https://github.com/MontrealCorpusTools/Montreal-Forced-Aligner.git to /private/var/folders/s5/v7w0tcn146s5dcch213_nkdw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-_f8yhwwt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × git version did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git version did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I tried the other way they say to install it on their website and tried "pip install montreal-forced-aligner" on both terminal's normal mode and after activating python because it said something about using python, and it didn't work for that either.  It also says "path not writable" a bunch.  Is that important?
Basically, what do these errors mean, and what recourse do you recommend?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52844867/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun

FYI, this package already provides a Conda Forge build (see Installation documentation). The documentation further outlines what packages should installed in the environment when building from source, which extends beyond what is tried here. Nevertheless, the duplicate marking seems appropriate: the errors indicate that the XCode  Command Line Tools need to be installed.
